# How to filter second time after grouping

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml document like this

```
<root>
  <e id="1" subid="1">
    <key>a</key>
  </e>
  <e id="2" subid="1">
    <key>a</key>
  </e>
  <e id="3" subid="2">
    <key>c</key>
  </e>
  <e id="4" subid="2">
    <key>d</key>
  </e>
</root>
```

I want to select groups of elements with the same subid but have different keys.

I guess I need to group them first

```
var ElementGroups = from E in Root.Elements("e")
                    group E by E.Attribute("subid") into Egroups
                    where ?.Element("key").distinct().count > 1
                    select Egroups
```

Do I have the right approach? I don't know how to refer to a particular element after grouping.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for that:

```
var ElementGroups = from E in Root.Elements("e")
                    group E by (string)E.Attribute("subid") into Egroups
                    where Egroups.Elements("key").Select(x => (string)x).Distinct().Count() > 1
                    select Egroups;
```

Comment: What does Egroups.ELements("key") mean? I debugged it, and found that Egroups.Elements() is the last element

Comment: Is there any reference about the IGrouping object?
E actually has a large number of sub elements. I want to write a function to differentiate distinct Es. How to refer IGrouping<XElement> as a parameter?

Comment: `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable<XElement>`, so `Egroups.Elements("key")` returns all elements with name `key` from all items the group.

Comment: But IEnumerable doesn't have Elements() implementation. Where does IGrouping.Elements() come from? And what does Select(x=>(string)x) do here? it shouldn't have any effect if there is no transformation involved

Comment: There is `IEnumerable<T>.Elements()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351784.aspx

Comment: I found out the answer to my question. The transformation is x=>(string)x from xelement to string.